# Kafka to Database data Pipelining

Tags: mysql, postgresql, apache-kafka

[image]I have data coming into Kafka, I want to push data from kafka to database(Postgresql).
I am following the steps of this link  "https://hellokoding.com/kafka-connect-sinks-data-to-postgres-example-with-avro-schema-registry-and-python/" and I am getting the error. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're getting is this:

```
Failed to deserialize the data for topic
Error deserializing Avro message
Unknown magic byte
```

This is because you have specified Avro converter, but the data in your topic is not Avro.

See this article for details: https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained

Comment: I updated my code and I am able to get data. But the flow I want is directly from Kafka topic to database, I want to skip this python code is that possible?

Comment: I am getting data into kafka via mqtt according to this link "https://github.com/kaiwaehner/kafka-connect-iot-mqtt-connector-example/blob/master/live-demo-kafka-connect-iot-mqtt-connector.adoc" so my kafka topic format is like mqtt.topicname, but this format is not accepted by the current python code. I am getting error when I use this topic.

Comment: for a new question/problem, start a new question post.

Answer (score 1):

This is no code required, this can be achieved by using Kafka connect and mysql connector available on Confluent.

https://www.confluent.io/hub/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc

Comment: yes, but it is not free. I took the trail period. Is there no other way to do it.

Comment: Apache Kafka is Apache 2.0 licensed, and includes Kafka Connect. The JDBC SInk connector is community licensed (https://www.confluent.io/confluent-community-license-faq) and is generally free to use.

Comment: Sure, thank you so much. Just one more thing, There are different data sources, from that data is coming to Kafka through mqtt. I want to pull that data from Kafka topic into the database, so how do I get this. @RobinMoffatt

Comment: @RobinMoffatt I have configured Postgresql in localhost and Im trying to poroduce message to topic but still no table created, followed this and later artcile also, https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-jdbc/sink-connector/index.html and https://hellokoding.com/kafka-connect-sinks-data-to-postgres-example-with-avro-schema-registry-and-python/

Comment: Why is there no data?: https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-jdbc-source-connector#why-no-data

Comment: I have updated my question with the screenshot of error I am getting, any help out of it?? @RobinMoffatt

Comment: Sure I will take care of it next time, as of now any thoughts on what might be wrong @RobinMoffatt

Comment: Yes I posted an answer.